# How extract from a string after specific word

Tags: r, regex

I have this string :

```
string <-"DIS_S_CD_EFS-NO_PCI-CD_ACT_CG-SOM_MT_ECT_CVE"
```

I need to extract only `SOM_MT_ECT_CVE` from it.

So for me the key word is `SOM` (identify its position ).

I tried using this :

```
d <-substr(gregexpr(pattern ='SOM',"DIS_S_CD_EFS-NO_PCI-CD_ACT_CG-SOM_MT_ECT_CVE"),
           nchar("DIS_S_CD_EFS-NO_PCI-CD_ACT_CG-SOM_MT_ECT_CVE"),"DIS_S_CD_EFS-NO_PCI-CD_ACT_CG-SOM_MT_ECT_CVE")
```

But it return NA values.

Comment: Extend you example input, so you will get more complete answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `sub` to match characters (`.*`) until 'SOM', capture the 'SOM' to the rest of the characters in a group (`(...)`) and in the replacement use the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub(".*(SOM_.*)", "\\1", string)
#[1] "SOM_MT_ECT_CVE"
```

---

Or using `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string, "SOM.*")
#[1] "SOM_MT_ECT_CVE"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split on the hyphen and get the last word, i.e.

```
tail(strsplit(string, '-', fixed = TRUE)[[1]], 1)
#[1] "SOM_MT_ECT_CVE"
```

Or with `word` from `stringr`,

```
stringr::word(string, -1, sep = '-')
#[1] "SOM_MT_ECT_CVE"
```